# Change font style and size using user input in Python TKinter textbox

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

This is a GUI program in which the user can change the font style and font size of the text box by clicking a button which opens a new window in which there are 2 listboxes in one there are different font styles and in the other there are font sizes and user can choose the font style and size. This is the code

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkfont

def font():
    root=tk.Tk()
    label3 = tk.Label(root)
    label3.grid(row=1, column=2)

    def select_style(event=None):
        try:
            try:
                font_index = listbox.curselection()
                font_index=font_index[0]
            except NameError:
                font_index=0
            label3.configure(font=fontStyle, text=fonts[font_index])
            text_box.configure(font=fontStyle)
        except IndexError:
            pass
        return font_index

    def select_size(event=None):
        try:
            try:
                font_size=listbox2.curselection()
            except NameError:
                font_size=18
            label3.configure(font=fontSize)
            text_box.configure(font=fontSize)
        except tk.TclError:
            pass
        return font_size

    fonts = list(tkfont.families())
    fontindex = select_style()
    fontsize = select_size()
    fontStyle = tkfont.Font(family=fonts[fontindex])
    fontSize = tkfont.Font(size=fontsize)
    label1 = tk.Label(root,text='font Style')
    label1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ew")

    listbox = tk.Listbox(root, height=8, width=34,
                         activestyle='dotbox', selectmode=tk.SINGLE)
    listbox2 = tk.Listbox(root, height=8, width=34,
                          activestyle='dotbox', selectmode=tk.SINGLE)
    listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', select_style)
    listbox2.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', select_size)
    for i in range(601):
        listbox2.insert(tk.END, i)
        for font in fonts:
            listbox.insert(tk.END, font)
        label2 = tk.Label(root, text='Font Size')
        label2.grid(row=2, column=0)
        scrollbar1 = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical",
                                  command=listbox2.yview)
        scrollbar1.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky="ns")
        listbox2.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar1.set)
        listbox2.grid(row=3, column=0)
        scrollbar2 = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical",
                                  command=listbox.yview)
        scrollbar2.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="ns")
        listbox.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar2.set)
        listbox.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew")

window = tk.Tk()
button = tk.Button(window, text='Font Size & Style', command=font)
text_box = tk.Text(window)
text_box.pack()
button.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

but i am getting a weird error when i am running it:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Computer\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1895, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:\Computer\Python\Python38-32\font.py", line 33, in font
    fontindex =select_style()
  File "D:\Computer\Python\Python38-32\font.py", line 15, in select_style
    label3.configure(font=fontStyle, text=fonts[font_index])
NameError: free variable 'fontStyle' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope
```

Comment: Please do not use pictures to show errors or code. They aren't searchable or copyable, and the visually impaired can't see them at all. Take the time to copy, paste, and format the error directly in the question.

Comment: ok i will do the changes

Comment: Is It Okay now?